# Does anyone have a faster method of removing the "$" symbol from a variable/input?

Tags: javascript

I quickly wrote up a small function to remove all "$" symbols from an input (input can either be a multi-digit number or a string of some kind):

```
parserFxn = function parserFxn(input){
  var data = input.split("");
  var init = [];

for(var i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; i++){
  if(data[i] !== "$"){
    init.push(data[i]);
  }
}

var result = init.join("");
return result;

}
```

Is there anything available that will do it a little bit faster? I'm not complaining about the speed because it's fairly quick, but if there is a better, faster method, I would love to hear it. Will upvote best answer quickly.

Comment: `data = data.replace(/\$/g, "")`

Comment: ^ there's that, and an inputs value is always a string, so it always works

Comment: I'm going to assume that using just replace in conjunction with regex is faster than if for loop + using join and push methods.